# Low power circuit design

Tags: power-supply, low-power

I want to design a low power circuit with stm32l micro and LoRa Module as its radio to send a sensor data to a gateway. The circuit is powered with a non rechargeable battery.

My problem is about its power circuit. I know that in order to decrease power consumption I have to decrease the quiescent current.

I want to turn on the circuit by turning on an LDO [STLQ020](http://www.st.com/en/power-management/stlq020.html) once a minute, and MCU in sleep mode is powered with a backup battery.

I  want to know if turning on and off the LDO is harmful for hardware? 
[image: Schematic]

Comment: I presume you mean keep it off most of the time, and turn it on once a minute? That doesn't hurt hardware, unless you design it pathologically. Suggest using CMOS for the timer for its very low idle power consumption, clocked slowly for low dynamic power consumption.

Comment: @Neil_UK yes I want to turn it on once a minute, but the wake up duration may vary from 6 ms to 20 ms, I want the MCU to say to regulator that I am done, and turn it off.

Comment: I agree with Neil, this should not be a problem for your hardware.  I think Maxim makes some ultra low power watchdog parts, as in a few nA, but I've not used them.